# Angular with Jasmine: mocking factory services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, factory

I have the following controller defined in Angular JS that uses a service from Angular Material:

```
angular.module('leopDirective', [])
    .controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log)
{

    $scope.mdSidenav = $mdSidenav;

    $scope.close = function () {
        $mdSidenav('left').close().then(function () {
            $log.debug("close LEFT is done");
            $scope.closed = true;
        });
    };

});
```

It depends on the service $mdSidenav that I am trying to mock with my own factory object:

```
describe('Controller: MenuCtrl', function() {
    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller, $q, menuCtrl,
        mock__mdSidenav = function(component) {
            return {
                isMock: true,
                component: component,
                close: function () {}
            }
        };

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('leopDirective', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('$mdSidenav', mock__mdSidenav);
        });
        inject(function ($injector) {
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
            $q = $injector.get('$q');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        });
        menuCtrl = $controller("MenuCtrl", { $scope: $scope });
    });

    it('should create the $mdSidenav object', function () {
        expect($scope.mdSidenav).toBeDefined();
    });

    describe('managing $mdSidenav', function () {
        it('should close the menu', function () {
            var data, deferred = $q.defer(), promise = deferred.promise;
            mock__mdSidenav.close = function() {
            return promise.then(function (response) {
                data = response.success;
            });
            $rootScope.$digest();
            $scope.close();
        };
    });
});
```

I have the code in the following [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tW4h1I?p=preview).

Apparently, the only thing that it is not working is my assignment of the $promise to the close() within the second "describe" block of the test. The execution of this test returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.close (app.js:7:35)
```

What makes me think that either the factory itself or the promise function are not correctly mocked up.

1. Is this the correct way for mocking a factory?
2. Is this the correct way for creating method that returns a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to test, but here's why you are getting this error message:

You are firing $scope.close(), which is not mocked. It is you original $scope.close method from MenuCtrl. The close method in turn fires $mdSidenav('left').close().then... and in the parameters of the test $mdSidenav('left').close() returns undefined which means that it has no then method.

If you want to control what happens you should either create a spy/mock for $scope.close or for $mdSidenav('left').close (which would mean mocking the $mdSidenav function to return an object with a spy/mock).

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do: I am trying to mock the "$mdSidenav" service from Angular Material. As you can see in the Jasmine code, I have created a mock object called "mock__mdSidenav" that I define as a function since the service is provided by a factory. I call $provide.value in order to replace the original service and then I create the "fake" promise return for the "close()" method (you can see that I redefined that method in the test within the second describe).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question can be found in the following post: [How to mock a service that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005037/angular-and-jasmine-how-to-mock-a-service-that-returns-a-promise)

Pretty much the key to make the code work is to use $q during the definition of the mocking object without caring about its resolution. Apparently, JavaScript will resolve it only once the mocking object has to be used.